# Insert element between elements within `this` in loop

Tags: jquery, html, loops, this, each

I have an `each` loop in which each looped element has the following html structure:

```
<li>
    <p>Text</p>
    <form>...</form>
</li>
```

In the loop I create a `<span>` element, which I want to insert in each looped element between the `<p>` and the `<form>` element. But I don't know how to access the elements within `this`, I just know how to insert it at the beginning (`prepend`) and end ('append') of the `li`, but not between the `<p>` and `<form>`.

Here is my code:

```
function calculation(elements) {
    $(elements).each(function() {
        ...
        var output = $('<span>').addClass('durationValue').html('Some Values..');
        $(this).append(output);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: You could use before() or after() to perform the append. http://api.jquery.com/before/ http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.after()` or `.before()` instead of `.append()` or `.prepend()` like so:

```
$(this).find("form").before(output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that I can use something like `find()` in the `this` context. :)